# Path difference between localhost and server?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I am developing an ASP.NET application. The application will be called *PFEP*. I have already set up an application pool and site for it in IIS, with the physical path of *D:\inetpub\wwwroot\PFEP*. Also set up a Git repo and made a local clone, started development, everything seemed fine.

But I have hit the following issue. The url of the application running on the server is:

> http://server-name.com/PFEP/Default.aspx

But when developing on my local clone and running it on localhost, the url shows as:

> http://localhost:58102/Default.aspx

As seen, the *PFEP* part is missing from the url in localhost. This results in the content urls not working properly, because if they are correct on localhost (like `src="../Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"`), they get messed up the server, because there it needs the PFEP in the path (like `src="../PFEP/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"`).

I though I fixed this by adding `<base href="~/" />` in the master page. With this tag the content like scripts, css and images show up fine. But now upon every button click the postback gets messed up as it tries to refresh to:

> [http://mc0vm00112.emea.bosch.com/PFEP/~/Default.aspx](http://mc0vm00112.emea.bosch.com/PFEP/%7E/Default.aspx)

or

> http://localhost:58102/~/Default.aspx

So uh...? What is the fix for this? I assume I should remove the `<base href="~/" />` tag and instead solve the content path issue on the live server by changing something in the IIS application pool or website. But what? Or change the base tag to something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, figured it out.

Simply using the content paths as `src="Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"`, without the `../` or `~/` seems to have solved the issue. Now content loads, and postbacks work properly on both localhost and on the server.

I just find this weird, because other projects have the exact same layout and seem to have the same application pool setup, yet had no issue with this previously.